# Compare two DF's and find differences in a specified column of different data types

Tags: r

I have two DF's with same column names but with different data types in them.

DF-1

[image]

DF-2

[image]

I want to compare above two DF's on column 'A' and write the difference to a new variable 'C'.

Problem here is I need to compare Alphanumeric values of "DF-1 column A" with Numeric values of "DF-2 column A" and find if the numerics in DF-2 are present in DF-1 or not.
If a value is not found in DF-1 then I want that difference to be written to new variable C below.

I want the variable C to be added to DF-1 like this with the differences identified.

[image]

Please advise.

Comment: Please include samples of your data as text, not pictures. It doesn't help anyone if multiple people have to retype your data just to get started.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience and Thank you for the advise. I will ensure that next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sub` to get only the number from `DF1$A` and use `%in%`to test if the number is present in `DF2$A`.

```
DF1$C <- ""
i <- !sub("\\D*", "", DF1$A) %in% DF2$A
DF1$C[i] <-DF1$A[i]  
DF1
#      A  B     C
#1 ABC 1 AA ABC 1
#2 ABC 2 AB      
#3 ABC 3 AC      
#4 ABC 4 AD      
#5 ABC 5 AE ABC 5
#6 ABC 6 AF ABC 6
#7 ABC 7 AG ABC 7
```

Data:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(A=paste("ABC", 1:7), B=paste0("A", LETTERS[1:7]))
DF2 <- data.frame(A=c(2:4,9:12), B=paste0("B", LETTERS[1:7]))
```